# scala - get total at the end of summation

Tags: scala

I have a List and I need to get the total count of the frequency operation as an additional element at the end of the result.

```
scala> val a = List("decimal","string","string","decimal","timestamp","decimal", "timestamp" )
a: List[String] = List(decimal, string, string, decimal, timestamp, decimal, timestamp)

scala> a.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0)){ case (acc,x) =>  acc+(x->(acc(x)+1))  }
res103: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(decimal -> 3, string -> 2, timestamp -> 2)
```

what I needed is

```
Map(decimal -> 3, string -> 2, timestamp -> 2, total -> 7)
```

I'm able to get with the below code

```
Map("total" -> a.size) ++ a.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0)){ case (acc,x) =>  acc+(x->(acc(x)+1))  }
```

But how to achieve with `a.foldLeft( Map("total" -> 0 ) )`. I'm trying something like below, but getting error.

```
scala> a.foldLeft( Map("total" -> 0 ) ){ case (acc,x) =>  acc+(x->(acc(x)+1))  }
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: decimal
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
```

Comment: `=> acc + (x->(acc(x)+1)) + ("total"->(acc("total")+1))`

Comment: @jwvh.. no that is also giving error

Comment: I tested it with your first posted code. `Map("total" -> 0)` is not needed.

Comment: @jwvh.. yes you are right, it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

```
val a = List("decimal","string","string","decimal","timestamp","decimal", "timestamp" )
a.foldLeft(Map("total" -> 0).withDefaultValue(0)) (
  (acc,x) =>
    acc.updated(x,acc(x) + 1)
       .updated("total",acc("total") + 1)
)
```

EDIT: I'm taking into account:

- the first comment of @jwvh by using operator `+` instead of updated for concision
- the second comment of @jwvh by removing `"total" -> 0` which is clearly unnecessary
- refactorizing incrementing values for both keys.

Solution becomes:

```
def incrementValOfKeys(acc: Map[String, Int], keys: String*) = keys.foldLeft(acc)(
  (acc, key) => acc + (key -> (acc(key) + 1))
)

val a = List("decimal","string","string","decimal","timestamp","decimal", "timestamp" )
a.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0)) (incrementValOfKeys(_, _, "total"))
```

in case you want to play with it: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/bAYBeNQ/0

`incrementValOfKeys` increments by `1` for a `Map[String, Int]` called `acc` each key's value given by `keys`.

The idea is that a call is iteratively done in `foldLeft`:
incrementValOfKeys(*map current state*, *current key*, "total")

Here's some examples of `incrementValOfKeys` which corresponds to iterative steps of computing `a` with the main `foldLeft` you've given in your question:

- `incrementValOfKeys(Map[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0), "decimal", "total")`
  gives `Map("decimal" -> 1, "total" -> 1)`
- `incrementValOfKeys(Map[String, Int]("decimal" -> 1, "total" -> 1).withDefaultValue(0), "string", "total")` gives `Map("decimal" -> 1, "total" -> 2, "string" -> 1)`
- `incrementValOfKeys(Map[String, Int]("decimal" -> 1, "total" -> 2, "string" -> 1).withDefaultValue(0), "string", "total")` gives `Map("decimal" -> 1, "total" -> 3, "string" -> 2)`
- etc.

You don't have to use `incrementValOfKeys` if you use `case (acc,x) => acc + (x->(acc(x)+1)) + ("total"->(acc("total")+1))` instead of calling it.

Comment: yes.. this works.. what is the need to give withDefaultValue(0) again?

Comment: your seed, at start, doesn't have other key than `"total"`. So you want the update to not fail when it encounter a new key, like `"decimal"`. Try without `.withDefaultValue(0)` and with a `a` set to `List("decimal")`. It'll fail and be self explanatory I hope.

Comment: yes.. but we already have ````Map("total" ->0)```` which has 0 as default right?

Comment: yes, but it's ok only for `"total"`, not for other keys. That's why `"decimal"` which has no value at first will throw an exception because on casual map you can't call `acc(x)` without an exception if the key hasn't been inserted before.

Comment: I've edited previous solution by removing `"total" ->0` @stack0114106 and giving a link to fiddle it. I hope it'll give you a better understanding if it's not already the case.

Comment: could you please add some explanation..you have introduced a function and I see 2 foldLeft and variable string argument.. little confused..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192693/discussion-between-benjamin-vialatou-and-stack0114106).

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to accumulate the total as you build the `Map`, you can just use the `size` of the input:

```
a.groupBy(identity).map{case (k, v) => k -> v.size} + ("total" -> a.size)
```

**Note**

The collection library in 2.13 has a new `groupMapReduce` method that will make this easier and more efficient, something like this:

```
a.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_+_) + ("total" -> a.size)
```